# Loops, which to use, and how to stop it

Tags: java, math, while-loop

My problem is: Suppose that one credit hour for a course is $100 at a school and that rate increases 4.3% every year. In how many years will the course’s credit hour costs tripled?

The rewrote this simple code many times, but just can't seem to get it.
I think i'm going about this the wrong way..

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MorenoJonathonCreditHourCostCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        double cost = 100;
        int years=0;
        double sum=200;
        double total;

        while (cost >= sum) {
            total = cost + 4.03;
            ++years;
        }

        System.out.println("The tuition will double in " + years + " years");
    }
}
```

Comment: A rate increase of 4.3% means to multiply the value by `1.043`

Comment: This `total = cost + 4.03;` is not a rate applied but an addition.

Comment: and your condition should be `total < 3 * cost` (or `<=`) and drop `sum` completely.

Comment: @luk2302 you mean `2 *`

Comment: I am assuming that Sum is the tripled Cost of 300 not 200.  Your condition should be something like Cost <= Sum.  you would need to update Cost each time through loop, Cost = Cost + (Cost*0.043)

Answer (score 1):

A rate increase of **4.3%** means that in every step, the value is 4.3% bigger than the previous value. This can be described by the following formula:

```
V_n+1 = V_n + (V_n * 4.3%)  
V_n+1 = V_n + (V_n * 0.043)  
V_n+1 = V_n * (1 + 0.043)  
V_n+1 = V_n * 1.043
```

In Java this boils down to simply `cost *= 1.043;`

You first stated *" In how many years will the course’s credit hour cost **tripled**"*, but in your program you actually check for when it has **doubled**.

I assume you want to calculate the triple cost, so your program should now look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double cost = 100;
    double tripleCost = 3 * cost;
    int years = 0;

    while(cost < tripleCost) {
        cost *= 1.043;
        years++;
    }
    System.out.println("It took " + years + " years.");
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
It took 27 years.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are adding to cost since it is a multiplication function:

FV(future value) = PV(present value) (1+r)^n

300 = 100(1.043)^n where you are looking for 'n'

Set up a while loop that operates while the future value is under 300 and adds to 'n'.